# Get_Connections command with Koala Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, koala-gem

I am running into an issue gathering the friends list from users using my app through the Koala Gem.

This also seems to be an issue that has popped up just recently. So I'm not sure if there have been some changes to the gem or the facebook API I am unaware of.

I used to use the following line of code to store my users friends list into an array:

```
<% @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends") %>
```

However instead of listing all of the friends in an array as it once did, this now returns the following error:

type: OAuthException, code: 1, message: An unknown error has occurred. [HTTP 500]

In my scope I have listed: 'basic_info' and 'user_friends'. Any suggestions on this bug?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is v2.0, then `/me/friends` only returns the friends which also use the app. It shouldn't produce a 500 in Koala, though. Check for the most recent Koala version.

Comment: I added the most recent Koala version and checked the documentation, but though /me/friends is what I should use. Do you know of a different piece of syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Check your keys and make sure they are ok. App Settings page. Try and get a new token and use that to make some test calls on the console.